# Compute CRC lookup table of poly CRC-32K/6.2

Tags: c, crc

I need the properties of poly `(0x992c1a4c; 0x132583499) <=> (0x992c1a4c; 0x132583499)` from [CRC Zoo](http://users.ece.cmu.edu/~koopman/crc/crc32.html).

I have read [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computation_of_cyclic_redundancy_checks) and [Ross N. Williams](http://www.ross.net/crc/download/crc_v3.txt) thoroughly but I can't make the final connection. Also I don't know how to check the generated table for correctness.

Do I need to take into account the endianness of the system where it is implemented? Can I use the reflected algorithm regardless of that? Which initial and XorOut values should I pick? How do I check my results?

Comment: Don't the "gold" links on that CRC Zoo page provide what you are asking for?

Comment: The gold data provides the Hamming Weights. I can't quite see how to use that to check correctness easily.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Trivia - the polynomial 0x132583499 is the product of 3 prime factors (carryless multiply):

```
0x3 * 0x3 * 0x5A12A42D = 0x132583499
```

> compute-crc-lookup-table

This depends if the crc is left shifted or right shifted. Assuming that the table is for working with one byte at a time, a 256 by 32 bit table is used. For a left shifting crc, the most signficant bit is masked off: 0x132583499 -> 0x32583499:

```
void gentbl(void)
{
uint32_t crc;
uint32_t b;
uint32_t c;
uint32_t i;
    for(c = 0; c < 0x100; c++){
        crc = c<<24;
        for(i = 0; i < 8; i++){
            b = crc>>31;
            crc <<= 1;
            crc ^= (0 - b) & 0x32583499;
        }
        crctbl[c] = crc;
    }
}
```

For a right shifting crc, the polynomial is reversed and right shifted 1 bit:   (0x132583499 reversed = 0x132583499, shifted right 1 bit = 0x992c1a4c.

```
void gentbl(void)
{
uint32_t crc;
uint32_t b;
uint32_t c;
uint32_t i;
    for(c = 0; c < 0x100; c++){
        crc = c;
        for(i = 0; i < 8; i++){
            b = crc&1;
            crc >>= 1;
            crc ^= (0 - b) & 0x992c1a4c;
        }
        crctbl[c] = crc;
    }
}
```

---

> Do I need to take into account the endianness of the system where it is implemented?

Only if the code loads or stores more than a byte at a time. This may be required if the symbol size is not the same as a byte.

> Can I use the reflected algorithm regardless of that (endianness)?

Yes, the endianness only affects the loading and storing of data. The reflected algorithm is used for right shifting crc, non-reflected for left shifting crc.

> Which initial and XorOut values should I pick?

This is arbitrary and depends on the specific crc. Initial value is typically all zero bits or all one bits with a few exceptions. XorOut is most often 0, but sometimes all one bits to post complement a crc.

> How do I check my results?

Use the code with the same initial, xorout, and polynomial as some crc used with an online calculator to verify some crc values. Note that endianness affects the output shown on some online calculators. The string size for an online calculator is limited, but even a few bytes should be enough to check the crc. If the table is created using code similar to the examples above, it's unlikely to have a mix of good and bad entries.

---

A 32 bit crc is the remainder produced by treating the message as a long n bit  dividend and dividing it by a 33 bit polynomial, resulting in a 32 bit remainder, which is the crc. The remainder is appended to the message, resulting in an encoded string of n+32 bits that is an exact multiple of the crc polynomial. If there are no errors and the crc is generated for the n+32 bit encoded string of bits, the crc will always be some constant, such as 0 if xorout == 0.

---

The crc zoo table contains additional information, such as a list of maximum number of data bits (before the 32 bit crc is appended) versus the Hamming Distance (HD), starting with HD=3, which means that every valid encoded string will differ by at least 3 bits from any other valid encoded string, and therefore any 2 bit error can be detected if the message length is not too long. You can click on the lengths to see an expanded list including failure examples, showing the indexes of the leading bits, and the last 32 bits of the message (somewhat confusing, I converted some of these to show all as indexes). There are 12 lengths shown, I added a 3rd row showing the lengths including the 32 bit crc:

```
HD = {    3,    4,    5,    6,  7,  8, 9,10,11,12,13,14
     {65506,65506,32738,32738,134,134,26,26,16,16, 3, 3}
     {65538,65538,32770,32770,166,166,58,58,48,48,35,35} +32 for crc
```

The web site includes examples of failures with crc poly of 0x132583499 when the message length is too long for a given hamming distance. For HD=3 or 4, encoded message with length (65538+1) 65539 bits, all zero bits except bit[0] and bit[65538] = 1, this will pass a crc check, even though there are 2 bits in error. For HD=5 or 6, encoded message length 32771, all zero bits except bit[{0, 1, 32769, 32770}] = 1, passes crc check with 4 bit error. For HD=7 or 8, encoded message length 167, all zero bits except bit[{0, 43, 44, 122, 123, 166}] = 1, passes crc check with 6 bit error. For HD=9 or 10, encoded message length 59, all zero bits except bit[{0, 5, 21, 25, 33, 37, 53, 58}] = 1, passes crc check with 8 bit error.

Comment: Great answer. All my points covered and some extras. Very useful. Thanks :)